# Sheets: indexOf not finding substring

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[image]

Working in apps script I have :

```
var conversations = row['CONVERSATION'].split('|');
var replies = conversations.map(function(message) { //ONLY CHECKED ROWS.
  var m = message.toString();
  return m.indexOf('R:')==true;
});  

    Logger.log(conversations);
    Logger.log(replies);
```

When I look at the logs:

```
[19-03-08 11:51:12:892 EST] [R: test3 ,  R: test3 ,  tx]
[19-03-08 11:51:12:893 EST] [false, true, false]
```

Why is the first element in the replies array false. Shouldn't it be true?

Comment: From the docs: The first index of the element in the array; -1 if not found. It will never return true. Maybe is position 0 that gets autocast to boolean?

Comment: A better question would be: Why is the second element true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the first element in the replies array false. Shouldn't it be
>   true?

So if the indexOf matches first element you get index as `0` and your condition is checking for `true` values but `0` is not so it is returning you false.

This will fail if your matched index is `0`

```
m.indexOf('R:') === true
```

Better you just check

```
m.indexOf('R:') !== -1
```

Ref: [**String.prototype.indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)